# Phase plane of simple pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, oscillators, phase-space

I'm trying to create a phase plane of simple pendulum motion by plotting $\dot\theta$ against $\theta$ in Matlab. I have the equation $\ddot\theta + \sin\theta = 0$, then by integrating I come to the formula for the energy of the pendulum $E = \frac{1}{2}\dot\theta^2 -\cos\theta$. I have tried plotting this in Matlab and I get the sinusoidal parts of the phase plane diagram, but not the elliptical parts (including the seperatrix). Am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

Comment: If you link $\dot\theta$ and $\theta$ as you have done then increasing $E$ should eventually do it: the hyperbolic solutions occur when there enough energy for $\dot\theta$ to be non-zero everywhere including at $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree, he's seeing the response dominated by the nonlinearity in his nonlinear model, for small angle $sin\theta = \theta$